# integration with a constant A

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the exact value of

$$\int^a_0 \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx$$

, where a is a positive constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^a\dfrac1{x+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx$$

Set $x=a\sin t$ to find $$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\cos t\ dt}{\sin t+\cos t}$$

Now use the concept of [Evaluate the integral $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin^3x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856)

Comment: hi i dont get how the sin^n x = sin^n (pi/2 - x)

Comment: @RStyle, where have u found this?

Comment: The further link u gave me

Comment: @RStyle, Refer to the formula mentioned in the first line