# Finding the value of $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dt}{1+(\tan(x))^{\sqrt{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> **The problem**: Find the value of $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+(\tan(x))^{\sqrt{2}}}$

I tried a few different substitutions and the closest I got to an okay looking integral is $$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^2 \, dt}{t^{1/\sqrt{2}}(1+\sqrt{t})},$$ which still looks scary. How do I approach this integral?

Comment: What does $gx$ mean?

Comment: It's $\tan(x)$, sorry. The dt was meant to be dx as well, fixed it.

Comment: This is an ancient Putnam problem so it wil be a battle of of the low hanging fruit sector here at MSE.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually works for 
$$
I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+(\tan x)^r},\ \ \ r\geq0
$$

Let $y=\pi/2-x$. Then
$$
I=\int_{\pi/2}^0\frac{-dy}{1+(\tan(\pi/2-x))^r}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dy}{1+\left(\frac1{\tan y}\right)^r}
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(\tan y)^r}{1+(\tan y)^r}\,dy.
$$
Then
$$
2I=I+I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+(\tan x)^r}+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(\tan x)^r}{1+(\tan x)^r}\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1+(\tan x)^r}{1+(\tan x)^r}\,dx=\frac\pi2.
$$
Then
$$
I=\frac\pi4.
$$

Comment: Did you mean $dv$ instead of $dy$?

Comment: Also I don't get why the bounds are changed back and forth

Comment: Yes, but there are more $y$, so I have changed $v$ to $y$. As for your second question: $x=0\ \implies\ y=\pi/2$; $x=\pi/2\ \implies\ y=0$; and $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=-\int_b^af(x)dx. $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may perform the change of variable $u=\dfrac \pi2 -x$ and observe that
$$
\left(\tan \left(\frac \pi2 -u\right)\right)^{\sqrt{2}}=\frac1{\left(\tan u\right)^{\sqrt{2}}}
$$ giving
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\left(\tan x\right)^{\sqrt{2}}}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\left(\tan x\right)^{\sqrt{2}}dx}{1+\left(\tan x\right)^{\sqrt{2}}}.
$$