# Is $\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\over a+b\tan^2x}\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\over a+b\cot^2x}\mathrm dx?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider these two integrals:

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\over a+b\tan^2x}\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\over a+b\cot^2x}\mathrm dx$$
>   where $(a,b)$ are real numbers

Are they equal, because it is trivial? I can't see it.

**Can** anyone demonstrate how they are equal?

Comment: $$\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, I think you need a - in front of your 2nd integral,

Comment: @user135711 No its correct.

Comment: Ok. Because of the cot and tan sign or s.t.?

Comment: I don't think the equality is true, although I can't prove it.

Comment: @user1952009 now you left off a minus sign

Comment: $\tan(x) = -\cot(x+\pi/2)$ and both are $\pi$-periodic @user135711 right at its zero $\cot'(z_0)=-1$

Comment: @user135711, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856

Comment: I'm just distracting from the question. @lab ahh, now I see. very correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By splitting the integration range in halves the first integral equals:
$$ 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{a+b\tan^2(x)} = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{(a+bt^2)(1+t^2)}$$
and the same applies to the second integral. Both equal $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dt}{(a+bt^2)(1+t^2)}$.