# Integrate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} {{x\sin^{100}x}\over \sin^{100}x+\cos^{100}x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} {{x\sin^{100}x}\over \sin^{100}x+\cos^{100}x}\,dx $$
Does anyone have any idea? I'm stuck on it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

First use $I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

so that $I+I=\int_a^b[f(x)+f(a+b-x)]\ dx\ \ \ \ (1)$

Then partition the ranges as $[0,\pi/2];[\pi/2,\pi];[\pi,3\pi/2];[3\pi/2,2\pi]$

In each four ranges apply $(1)$ again.

**Generalization**:
For,
$$J=\int_{m\cdot\pi/2}^{(m+1)\pi/2}\dfrac{\sin^nx}{\cos^nx+\sin^nx}dx$$

$\sin\left(\dfrac{m\pi}2+\dfrac{(m+1)\pi}2-x\right)=\sin\left(m\pi+\dfrac\pi2-x\right)=(-1)^m\cos x$

Similarly,
 $\cos\left(\dfrac{m\pi}2+\dfrac{(m+1)\pi}2-x\right)=(-1)^m\sin x,$

If $g(x)=\dfrac{\sin^nx}{\cos^nx+\sin^nx},$

$g\left(\dfrac{m\pi}2+\dfrac{(m+1)\pi}2-x\right)=\cdots=\dfrac{\cos^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}$

$$\implies J+J=\int_{m\cdot\pi/2}^{(m+1)\pi/2}\dfrac{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}{\cos^nx+\sin^nx}dx=\cdots=\dfrac{(m+1)\pi}2-\dfrac{m\pi}2=?$$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856

Comment: I did what u say, and after i apply (1) in each four, I don't know how to continue...One more hint please?

Comment: @Andrew, What is your $$I+I=?$$  Please find the updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much, I solve the integral and I understood how to do it! Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. By the change of variable
$$
x \to 2\pi-x,
$$ one gets
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} {{x\sin^{100}x}\over \sin^{100}x+\cos^{100}x}\:dx =\int_{0}^{2\pi} {{(2\pi-x)\sin^{100}x}\over \sin^{100}x+\cos^{100}x}\:dx 
$$ then one may obtain a standard integral.

Comment: +1: But how do you continue? You still have the sum in the denominator?

Comment: I also try that before to post it, but from there i didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

After the reduction (by symmetry, $x\mapsto 2\pi-x$) to 
$$\pi\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^{100}(x)}{\sin^{100}(x)+\cos^{100}(x)}\,dx=2\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^{100}(x)}{\sin^{100}(x)+\cos^{100}(x)}\,dx$$
we may still apply a symmetry argument ($x\mapsto \frac{\pi}{2}-x$) to turn the last integral into
$$ 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^{100}(x)+\cos^{100}(x)}{\sin^{100}(x)+\cos^{100}(x)}\,dx = \color{red}{\large\pi^2}.$$
You may replace $100$ with any positive even integer and the answer stays the same.

Comment: Thank you too! More easier.