# Hint for integration $\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{3x^2}{1+e^x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I found the following problem in JEE-Advanced (2014) question paper:

> $$\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{3x^2}{1+e^x}\mathrm dx$$

At present, I don't know how to approach the problem. So, a few good hints would be appreciated.

(It seems there is no closed form for the antiderivative of the function.)

Comment: Use the pattern from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856

Comment: $$\frac{1}{1+e^x}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} = 1 $$ and you may easily exploit symmetry.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $u=-x$.

\begin{align}
\int_{-2}^2\frac{3x^2}{1+e^x}dx&=\int_2^{-2}\frac{-3u^2}{1+e^{-u}}du\\
&=\int_{-2}^2\frac{3u^2}{1+e^{-u}}du\\
&=\int_{-2}^2\frac{3u^2e^u}{1+e^{u}}du\\
&=\int_{-2}^2\frac{3x^2e^x}{1+e^x}dx
\end{align}

So

$$2\int_{-2}^2\frac{3x^2}{1+e^x}dx=\int_{-2}^2\frac{3x^2}{1+e^x}dx+\int_{-2}^2\frac{3x^2e^x}{1+e^x}dx=3\int_{-2}^2x^2dx$$

Comment: Slick. (+1) ${}$

Comment: I don't understand the 3rd line.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_2^{-2}\frac{-3u^2}{1+e^{-u}}du=\int_{-2}^2\frac{3x^2e^x}{1+e^x}dx$? Multiply both the denominator and numerator by $e^u$, then replace the dummy variables by $x$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't which part you are referring to. The 3rd line is "So".

Comment: but u=-x right? Then, it would change the whole expresseion to the previous one!

Comment: The previous line of "So"

Comment: damnn hella smart +1

Comment: @Mockingbird360 I just edited the proof to make it easier to read. Do you mean $\int_{-2}^2\frac{3u^2e^u}{1+e^{u}}du=\int_{-2}^2\frac{3x^2e^x}{1+e^x}dx$? It is to replace the dummy variable.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. but u=-x? what about that?

Comment: For definite integrals, variables sometimes are not really "variables" and can be replaced by other "variables". For example, $\int e^xdx$ and $\int e^udu$ are not the same,  as the first one is $e^x+C_1$ and the second one is $e^x+C_2$. But $\int_1^2e^xdx$ and $\int_1^2e^udu$ are actually the same. Both of them are equal to $e^2-e$. $\int_{-2}^2\frac{3u^2e^u}{1+e^{u}}du$ and $
\int_{-2}^2\frac{3x^2e^x}{1+e^x}dx$ are the same, the "variables" $x$ and $u$ are called dummy variables. The value of the definite integrals does not depend on $u$ or $x$

Comment: I just replace $u$ by $x$ as the integrals are the same after the replacement. This is not a substitution.

Comment: Very cool. Would you mind sharing the motivation for this idea? I graphed $\displaystyle \dfrac {3x^2}{1+x^2}$ and $\dfrac {3x^2}{1+x^2} \cdot e^x$ and indeed, the functions are reflections of each other with respect to the $x$ axis. But I would've never guessed it.

Comment: @Ovi As the indefinite integral has closed form in terms of elementary functions, not much I can do. $u=-x$ is a natural choice of substitution since it keeps the upper and the lower limits. This skill is common in examination papers.

Comment: @CYAries Thanks for the response. But if you don't mind, how did you know the indefinite integral does not have a closed form in terms of elementary functions? When I saw the question title my first idea was to try integration by parts and hope to get a closed form.

Comment: @Ovi I think it is hard to answer your question completely. You may refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral. Many indefinite integrals has no closed form in elementary functions. When you tried all possible common skills without success, it is likely that the integral is one the those.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will check out the link.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question has been answered in a similar way, I would like to throw some light on the general strategy for solving definite integrals of this sort. Let us consider $I=\int_a^b f(x) dx$. Substitute $u=a+b-x$. $$I=\int_a^bf(x)dx=-\int_b^af(a+b-x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx \tag1$$Note that this property is useful especially when $f(x)$ is a rational function whose denominator remains the same upon this substitution. Considering the integral the OP has asked. Let $$I=\int_{-2}^2\dfrac{3x^2}{1+e^x}dx=\int_{-2}^{2}\dfrac{3x^2e^x}{1+e^x}dx \implies I=\dfrac{x^3}{3}\mid_0^2=8$$
**Note**: This answer is written keeping the typology of JEE Definite Integration questions in mind. Definite Integration questions in the JEE usually requires one to make use of formula $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own method.

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{3x^2}{1+e^x}\mathrm dx$$
$$=\int_{-2}^{0} \frac{3x^2}{1+e^x}\mathrm dx+ \int_{0}^{2}\frac{3x^2}{1+e^x}\mathrm dx $$

For $x\in[-2,0]$ the fraction $\dfrac{3x^2}{1+e^x}$ becomes $\dfrac{3x^2 e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}$

So, $\displaystyle\int_{-2}^{0} \frac{3x^2}{1+e^x}\mathrm dx $ becomes

$$\int_{0}^{2}\frac{3x^2 e^x}{1+e^x}\mathrm dx$$

Now the expression simplifies,
$$\int_{0}^{2}\frac{3x^2e^x}{1+e^x} \mathrm dx+ \int_{0}^{2}\frac{3x^2}{1+e^x}\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{2} 3x^2\mathrm dx $$
= 8; which is the answer in my key.

Comment: This is essentially the same method as mine, except it breaks down the range of integration. Do you understand this key?

Comment: Yes, I do understand. I have explained it further.

Comment: Your solution is perfectly OK. But I think it would be better if you can understand my solution as this is a common method to handle this type of problems. The link in the comment by lab bhattacharjee is good.

Comment: This answer should be removed.