# Calculation of integral $\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x + \sqrt{a-x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have tried calculating the integral:

> $$ \int_0^a\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x + \sqrt{a-x}}\mathrm{d}x $$

but getting rid of the square roots from the problem is like impossible for me.

Comment: Take carefully to my editing: is that what you meant to write? Be careful...

Comment: yes thanks alot

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $x=a\,\sin^2(u)$?

Comment: Substitute $x\to x-a$ and then add the resulting integral to the initial one. Good luck

Comment: Set $x/a=\sin^2t$ and use  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856

Comment: Hi, Doris, you asked this yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321871/please-integrate-int-frac-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrta-x-dx

Comment: **Duplicate of question**, asked yesterday: **https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321871/please-integrate-int-frac-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrta-x-dx**

Comment: The duplicate target is not quite a duplicate, because this time we have a definite integral, and can use the obvious symmetry. That trick has been seen here enough many times already, so I'm all for closing. But, the askers are either housemates or aliases, so I have to ask. Wilmot, why didn's you edit the first version into shape. Why reask?

Comment: because i do not know who ask the question first

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $u=a-x$. Then

$$\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a-x}}dx=\int_a^0\frac{-\sqrt{a-u}}{\sqrt{a-u}+\sqrt{u}}du=\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{a-x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a-x}}dx$$

So

$$2\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a-x}}dx=\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a-x}}dx+\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{a-x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a-x}}dx=\int_0^adx$$

Comment: How did you go from the second expression to the third expression in the first line ($a-u \rightarrow a-x$)

Comment: $u$ and $x$ are dummy variables. The integrals do not depend on them. If $F(x)=\int\frac{\sqrt{a-x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a-x}}dx$, then $F(u)=\int\frac{\sqrt{a-u}}{\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{a-u}}du$. So, $\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{a-x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a-x}}dx=F(a)-F(0)$ and $\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{a-u}}{\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{a-u}}du=F(a)-F(0)$. They are the same and we can simply rename $u$ by $x$.

Comment: makes sense - just a simple renaming, not a substitution. I also just noticed that the values being integrated in first and third expressions are reflections around $x=a/2$, so the integrals from 0 to $a$ must be equal.

Comment: Yes, that's why we choose this substitution.

Answer (score 3):

Try exploiting the fact that
$$\int_0^af(x)=\int_0^af(a-x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write your Integrand in the form
$$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\frac{a-x}{x}}}$$ and set $$t=\sqrt{\frac{a-x}{x}}$$
if you do that then you will get the indefinite integral
$$-a\int\frac{2t}{(1+t)(t^2+1)}dt$$