# Integration problem (no 9-14)

Tags: calculus, integration

I've learnt ibp, substitution.. but it seemed that i cannot just use those to solve the problem..  Please help me..

$$\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \sin(x^3) \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: -1<x<1 ........

Comment: Do you mean the integral $\int_{-1}^1 \sin(x^3) dx$ (you can type that in yourself by placing `\int_{-1}^1 \sin(x^3) dx` inside a pair of `$`)

Comment: This is a poor duplicate of the suggested duplicate. The key there is that one can evaluate this integral: but that's hard. The key that makes this easy is that it's an odd function integrated symmetrically across its axis, and thus is zero.

Comment: It would be better if you used a more informative title, as well as correct spelling and grammar within your post. Further, you mentio nthat this is no9-14, which I assume refers to a book? But you haven't said which book.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and the $f(x)=x^3$ are odd function, so they satisfy the following equation: $f(-x)=-f(x)$.
$$\sin((-x)^3)=\sin(-x^3)=-\sin(x^3)$$
So $\sin(x^3)$ is also an odd function.
The integral of the odd functions from $-a$ to $a$ is $0$:
$$\int\limits_{-a}^{a} f(x) \mathrm{d}x=0$$
So:
$$\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \sin(x^3) \mathrm{d}x=0$$
A little "proof":
$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{a} f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$
Substitute $u=-x$, $\mathrm{d}u=-\mathrm{d}x$:
$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{-a} f(-u) (-\mathrm{d}u)$$
We can change the order of limits:
$$I=-\int\limits_{-a}^{0} f(-u) (-\mathrm{d}u)$$
$$I=\int\limits_{-a}^{0} f(-u) \mathrm{d}u$$
But because $f(-x)=-f(x)$:
$$I=-\int\limits_{-a}^{0} f(u) \mathrm{d}u$$
Replacing $u$ with $x$, and multiplyng by $-1$:
$$\int\limits_{-a}^{0} f(x) \mathrm{d}x=-I$$
So the $2$ equation for $I$:
$$\int\limits_{-a}^{0} f(x) \mathrm{d}x=-I$$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{a} f(x) \mathrm{d}x=I$$
Adding the $2$ together:
$$\int\limits_{-a}^{0} f(x) \mathrm{d}x+\int\limits_{0}^{a} f(x) \mathrm{d}x=I-I$$
$$\int\limits_{-a}^{a} f(x) \mathrm{d}x=0$$
Note: This method only works if both of the integrals exist, so $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) \mathrm{d}x \neq 0$, because neither the $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0} \sin(x) \mathrm{d}x$ nor the $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \sin(x) \mathrm{d}x$ exist.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Evaluate the integral $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin^3x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856),

$$I=\int_{-a}^a\sin(x^{2n+1})dx=\int_{-a}^a\sin[\{a+(-a)-x\}^{2n+1}]dx=\cdots=-I$$

as $\sin(-u)=-\sin u$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \sin(x^3) \mathrm{d}x \overset{u=-x}{=}-\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \sin(u^3) \mathrm{d}u = -I$$

Then $$2I=0\implies I=0$$