# Struggling to solve this integral

Tags: integration

I've tried a lot to solve this and couldn't. it's frustrating.
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{xe^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{\cos (x) + 4}} \ dx
$$

Comment: The function looks odd. It’s probably nothing.

Comment: Use the formula:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856

Comment: $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{xe^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{\cos (x) + 4}} \ dx=0$$ since $x\mapsto  \frac{xe^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{\cos (x) + 4}} $ is an odd function

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

You are integrating $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx,\;$ but note that
$$
f(-x) = \frac{-xe^{-|-x|}}{\sqrt{\cos (-x) + 4}}
      = -\frac{xe^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{\cos (x) + 4}}
      = -f(x),
$$
so $f$ is an odd function. Then, substitute $y = -x$ to get
$$
\int_{-1}^0 f(x) dx
 = - \int_1^0 f(-y) dy
 = - \int_1^0 - f(y) dy
 = \int_1^0 f(y) dy
 = -\int_0^1 f(y) dy
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah. thanks a lot!