# Evaluate $\int_{1}^{2} \ \frac{\arctan (x)}{\arctan \left (\frac{1}{x^2-3x+3} \right )} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

In this exercise, we are given two integrals $I$ and $J$:

$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx} dx, \quad n\in \mathbb{N^*},$$
and
$$J = \int_{1}^{2} \frac{\arctan(x)}{\arctan \left (\frac{1}{x^2-3x+3} \right )} \, dx.$$

I know that $I = \pi/4$  but I do not understand the association between $I$ and $J$.

This exercise is found in a lesson on substitution so maybe there is no association between the two integrals, but $J$ should be $1.108205454429995$.

Comment: For the first one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856

Comment: For the second, $$\arctan\dfrac1{x^2-3x+3}=\arctan\dfrac{(x-1)-(x-2)}{1+(x-1)(x-2)}$$

$$=\arctan(x-1)-\arctan(x-2)$$

Comment: Could it be a problem of approximation ?

Comment: $ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(x-a)}{f(x-a) + f(b-x)} dx = \frac{b-a}{2} $

Comment: we need $ \int_{1}^{2} \frac{\arctan(x-1)}{\arctan(x-1)+arctan(2-x)} dx =1/2 $ but the numerator is $ arctan(x) $ so maybe it's a typing error :s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suspected, there may be one more typo in the textbook.

As I commented, I was wondering if approximation would be require. So, for the fun of it, I tried to.
$$I=\int_1^2\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{\tan ^{-1}(2-x)-\tan ^{-1}(1-x)}\,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\tan ^{-1}(y+1)}{\tan ^{-1}(y)-\tan ^{-1}(y-1)}\,dy$$

Using Taylor expansions built around $y=0$
$$\tan(y+a)=\tan ^{-1}(a)+\frac{y}{a^2+1}-\frac{a y^2}{\left(a^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{\left(3
   a^2-1\right) y^3}{3 \left(a^2+1\right)^3}+\frac{\left(a-a^3\right)
   y^4}{\left(a^2+1\right)^4}+O\left(y^5\right)$$ leads to
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}(y+1)}{\tan ^{-1}(y)-\tan ^{-1}(y-1)}=\frac{\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{y^3}{12}+O\left(y^5\right) }{\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{4}-\frac{5 y^3}{12}+O\left(y^5\right) }$$ Using long division, the integrand is
$$1+\frac{2 y^3}{\pi }-\frac{4 y^4}{\pi ^2}+O\left(y^5\right)$$ leading to
$$I_{(5)}=1+\frac{1}{2 \pi }-\frac{4}{5 \pi ^2}\approx 1.07810$$ which is not fantastic.

For sure, we could continue the expansions and get
$$I_{(6)}=1+\frac{1}{3 \pi }+\frac{31}{105 \pi ^2}+\frac{4}{21 \pi ^3}-\frac{16}{7 \pi ^4}\approx 1.11870$$
$$I_{(7)}=1+\frac{19}{48 \pi }+\frac{143}{840 \pi
   ^2}-\frac{145}{84 \pi ^3}+\frac{5}{7 \pi ^4}+\frac{4}{\pi ^5}\approx 1.10798$$
$$I_{(8)}=1+\frac{19}{48 \pi }-\frac{493}{1512 \pi ^2}-\frac{409}{756 \pi
   ^3}+\frac{33}{7 \pi ^4}-\frac{28}{9 \pi ^5}-\frac{64}{9 \pi ^6}\approx 1.10635$$

Now, I give up !

Comment: Nicely done! We don't study Taylor series in highschool but I guess I should check them out cause they seem essential.

Comment: @SADBOYS. Don't worry ! You will learn them and use them a lot (all problems with limits can be solved with them). I must confess that I felt in love with Taylor (series) more than 60 years ago and I use them almost daily. As I wrote, I made it for the fun (suspecting, as you did, a typo in the book). Cheers.