# Integrating trigonometric function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do you integrate:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(1-x)+\sin(x)}dx$$

The answer that you must get is $\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Now let $1-x = y $ to get $I=-\int_{1}^{0} \frac{\sin(1-y)}{\sin(1-y)+\sin(y)} dy$

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). In the present form, the integral doesn't exist, though it's hard to tell if you just forgot a pair of parentheses.

Comment: Oh yes I assumed two terms in denominator, only then we get that result..

Comment: Set $y=\dfrac{\pi x}2$ and use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856

Comment: @Lab why do you need that pi/2 ? You can directly use your answer!

Comment: @KingTut, With that transformation, the integrals become identical, right?

Comment: I was saying whats the harm in directly applying your answer's method. well i dont mind..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I=\int_0^1\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\sin (1-x)}\,dx~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$

Take $x=1-z$. Then $I=\int_0^1\frac{\sin (1-z)}{\sin (1-z)+\sin (z)}\,dz$. Or we can write it as 
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\sin (1-x)}{\sin x+\sin (1-x)}\,dx~~~~~~~~~(2)$$

Add $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have

$$2I=\int_0^1 1\,dx \implies I=\frac{1}{2}.$$