# Find $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^3 x}{e^x+1} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the value of the following integral

$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^3 x}{e^x+1} dx
$$

I tried to use the twin integral with sin and get some result but nothing obvious came out. Also, Mathematica gives a very bizarre result! Any ideas how to solve analytically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating $\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)+1}{b^x+1}\,\mathrm dx$ for a $y$-axis symmetrical function $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063941/evaluating-int-aa-fracfx1bx1-mathrm-dx-for-a-y-axis-symmetr)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**: make the substitution $x\mapsto -x$ and add the two integrals. The result should be $2/3$.

Comment: Thank for the hint. The sum of the two equal integrals is 2/3. Isn't the final result 1/3?

Comment: Are you sure the sum is 2/3? According to WA, $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^3(x)\,dx=4/3$.

Comment: the integrand is $\dfrac{\cos^3(x)}{e^x+1}$, not just $\cos^3(x)$.

Comment: @user477343 But the sum of $\dfrac{\cos^3(x)}{e^x+1}$ and $\dfrac{\cos^3(x)}{e^{-x}+1}$ is $\cos^3(x)$.

Comment: @iqcd you are right. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, indeed you are, as a matter of fact :)

Answer (score 3):

Like [Evaluate the integral $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin^3x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}\,\mathrm dx$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856),

if $\displaystyle I=\int_{-a}^a\dfrac{g(x)\ dx}{b^x+1}$

$\displaystyle I=\int_{-a}^a\dfrac{g(a-a-x)\ dx}{b^{a-a-x}+1}$

If $g(x)=g(-x)$ i.e., an even function,

$\displaystyle I=\int_{-a}^ag(x)\ dx$

Here $g(x)=\cos^3x=\dfrac{\cos3x+3\cos x}4$