# Problem from the 2020 Latvian "Sophomore's Dream" competition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

> Evaluate $$\int_{-a\pi}^{a\pi} \frac{\cos^5(x)+1}{e^x+1}dx, \quad a \in \mathbb{N}$$

In the beginning, I didn't have any ideas of how to solve this. The one that later came to mind was to try using Feynman's technique, but I couldn't think of the proper function to use for the second variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, but one directions which looks potentially interesting is to write the cosine as a complex exponent

Comment: Another potential approach would be to expand $(1+e^x)^{-1}$ as a geometric series, integrate term-by-term, and sum; the sum that comes out of this might be stickier than the initial integral, though...

Comment: One idea is to write this as a complex contour integral with a $z = e^{ix}$ substitution, but then the $e^x \mapsto z^i$ on the bottom becomes tricky.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2777663/find-int-pi-2-pi-2-frac-cos3-xex1-dx)

Comment: What is the direction? What is one asked to do with this expression?

Comment: Is the competition over?

Comment: @shoover yes it is over

Comment: Strongly related: [Evaluating $\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)+1}{b^x+1}\,\mathrm dx$ for a $y$-axis symmetrical function $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3063941/631742)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Let $I$ be our integral. Substitute $t=-x \Rightarrow dt = -dx$. Then:

$$I=\int_{-a\pi}^{a\pi} \frac{\cos^5 t+1}{e^{-t}+1}\,dt=\int_{-a\pi}^{a\pi} \frac{e^t(\cos^5 t+1)}{e^{t}+1}\,dt=\int_{-a\pi}^{a\pi} \frac{e^x(\cos^5 x+1)}{e^{x}+1}\,dx$$

Therefore:

$$2I=\int_{-a\pi}^{a\pi} \frac{e^x(\cos^5 x+1)}{e^{x}+1}\,dx+\int_{-a\pi}^{a\pi} \frac{\cos^5 x+1}{e^{x}+1}\,dx=\int_{-a\pi}^{a\pi} (\cos^5 x+1)\,dx$$

$$=\bigg[x + \frac{5}{8} \sin(x) + \frac{5}{48} \sin 3 x + \frac{1}{80} \sin 5 x\bigg]_{-a\pi}^{a\pi}=2a\pi$$

Thus $I=a\pi$.

Comment: +1 elegant answer Atticus

Comment: More generally, if $f$ is even, then $$\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{f(x)}{e^{x}+1}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: @MathIsFun7225 I showed this on this forum about [a year ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3063941/631742) as one of the first things that I did on here