# $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^{n}x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve the integral:
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^{n}x}dx$$
I have tried several methods shown below:
$$I(n)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^nx}dx$$
$x=\arctan(u)$
$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+u^n}\frac{1}{1+u^2}du$$
but this does not seem to lead anywhere. I also tried:
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^ax}dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(\tan x)}{\left(1+\tan^ax\right)^2}dx$$
but this just seems to complicate it more.

I also see that it can be expressed as:
$$I(b)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^b(x)}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^b(x)}{\cos^b(x)+\sin^b(x)}dx$$
a final thought is using the identity:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$
so:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^b(x)}{\cos^b(x)+\sin^b(x)}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^b(x)}{\sin^b(x)+\cos^b(x)}$$
and therefore:
$$2I(b)=\int_0^{\pi/2}1dx=\pi/2$$
$$I(b)=\pi/4$$
$$I=\pi/4$$
does this work? Thanks

Comment: Your last attempt does work. It is $\pi/2$. I handled a very, very similar integrand [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2945748/357390).

Comment: yes $\tan^\pi(x)=(\tan x)^\pi$

Comment: @terrace: wtf else could it be?

Comment: i agree, there would only be ambiguity if it said $\tan x^\pi$

Comment: How is this a duplicate they are literally different questions

Comment: @HenryLee In fact, the two questions are almost identical, and the highest rated answer to the older question completely answers your question.

Comment: Doesn’t that make it a useful source rather than a duplicate then?

Comment: The last part of this question is a duplicate. That doesn't make it a duplicate question.

Comment: I've nominated to reopen this because I challenge the duplicate. The two questions are amenable to the same solution technique, but the problems themselves are very different. Besides which, good luck finding the unique oldest problem on here solvable that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to remark that your substitution $x = \arctan{u}$ works too; as follows:

Let $u \mapsto {u}^{-1}$ then 
$\displaystyle I(n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+{u}^{-n}}\frac{1}{1+u^{-2}} \cdot \frac{1}{u^2}\,du  =\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+{u}^{-n}}\frac{1}{1+u^{2}} \, du$

Hence $\displaystyle 2I(n) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^2+1}\bigg(\frac{1}{1+u^n}+\frac{1}{1+u^{-n}}\bigg)\,du$ but $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+u^n}+\frac{1}{1+u^{-n}} = 1$.

Hence $\displaystyle 2I(n) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^2+1}\,{du} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ therefore $\displaystyle I(n) = \frac{\pi}{4}$ as you have correctly found.

Answer (score 2):

Seems fine, but you got a typo at the last part. It should be $I(b) = \pi/4$ not $\pi/2$. Also we could do this quicker:
$$
I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac {\mathrm dx} {1+\tan(x)^\pi} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac {\mathrm dx} {1 + \cot(x)^\pi} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac {\tan(x)^\pi \mathrm dx}{1+ \tan(x)^\pi} \implies 2I = \frac \pi 2 \implies I = \frac \pi 4.  
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use $$\int _a^b f(a+b-x)dx=\int_a^b f(x)dx$$ and see the magic happen. The answer is $\frac{\pi}{4
}$ actually it's true for any non-negative number
.

Comment: have you read the end of my answer

Comment: I just mean the answer in general, and why is it not true for all positive numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The usual method for integrals of this form is to use

$$t=\tan\frac{u}{2}$$

Comment: that would give a polynomial to the power of and unknown number (or $\pi$) and it doesn't really work