# Evaluate $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^3 x\cdot f(\cos x){\rm d}x$

Tags: definite-integrals

## Probem

Evaluate
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^3 x\cdot f(\cos x){\rm d}x.$$

Thanks to @NewBornMATH's hint. It's easy to verify that the integrand is an odd function，and the integral interval is symmetric with respect to the original point. Hence the integral value must be zero!

Comment: From the even odd property it seems to be 0. Consider $g(x)=(sin(x))^{3}.f(cosx)$ then note that $g(-x)=-g(x)$ hence integral from any $(-a,a)$ will be zero.

Comment: @NewBornMATH Oh，yes！It's easy to verify that the integrand is an odd function，and the integral interval is symmetric with the original point. Hence the Integral value must be zero！ thanks.!

Comment: Well ! You are welcome. You can upvote my comment if it helped.

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856