# Integration of $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{\sec^2x}{1+e^x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Actually I got stuck in a integration it is $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{\sec^2x}{1+e^x}dx$$

I tried multipying and dividing by $\tan x$ and then substitution but nothing worked for me. I am not understanding the way to solve it. Please give me a hint to start for this integration.

Comment: The value is $1$.  (By the way, please use MathJax.)

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Comment: Sry but I don't know how to use mathjax

Comment: Then please learn how to use. Writing math expressions without MathJax is discouraged, and may cause down votes.

Comment: Thank you I will learn mathjax soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**
For a even function $f(x)$, we have
$$\int_{-a}^a\frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx\\
=\frac12\left(\int_{-a}^a\frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx+\int_{-a}^a\frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx\right)\\
=\frac12\left(\int_{-a}^a\frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx+\int_{-a}^a\frac{f(-x)}{1+e^{-x}}dx\right)\\
=\frac12\left(\int_{-a}^a\frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx+\int_{-a}^a\frac{f(x)}{1+e^{-x}}dx\right)\\
=\frac12\int_{-a}^a\left(\frac{1}{1+e^x}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right)f(x)dx\\
=\frac12\int_{-a}^a1\cdot f(x)dx$$
Now, substitute $a=\frac{\pi}4$ and $f(x)=\sec^2x$.

Comment: Oh thank you I got it .