# Integrate $\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\sin^{2019}(x)e^{-x^4}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I'm following a course on analysis and I am supposed to compute the following integral:

$\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\sin^{2019}(x)e^{-x^4}dx$.

I've been trying to use the integration by part but I've been stuck for a while. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856  and the given function is odd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just substitute $x=-t$ and you will get that: $$I=\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\sin^{2019}(x)e^{-x^4}dx=-\int_{-1}^{1}t^2\sin^{2019}(t)e^{-t^4}dt=-I$$
$$I=-I\Rightarrow I=0$$

Comment: Oh... right! I can't believe I was actually trying to compute the primitive. Thanks

Comment: I believe it's a good thing that you already tried to compute the primitive, that is how in the future you will be able to see faster when you can find a primitive for an integral, by trying and failing in the past and earning experience. So no worries at all, keep it up!

Answer (score 6):

The integrand is an odd function.

For any odd (integrable) function $f$, we have

$$\int_{-a}^a f = 0$$

Therefore, the integral is equal to $0$.