# Use change of variable $ y=\frac{\pi}{2}-x $ to evaluate a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

It appears in my guide : the title exercise shows me the inicial substitution
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cfrac{\sqrt{\sin x}\ dx }{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}} & = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cfrac{\sqrt{\sin (\pi/2-y)}\ dy }{\sqrt{\sin (\pi/2-y)}+\sqrt{\cos (\pi/2-y)}} \\
 & = -\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\cfrac{\sqrt{\cos y}\ dy }{\sqrt{\cos y}+\sqrt{\sin  y}} \quad note \ that \sin  (\pi/2-y)= \cos y, and \cos(\pi/2-y)=\sin y    \\ 
 & = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cfrac{\sqrt{\cos y}\ dy }{\sqrt{\cos y}+\sqrt{\sin  y}} /* \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{\cos y}} \\
 & =  \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{\tan y}} \\ 
 & = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cfrac{2u \ du}{\sec^2u(1+u)} \  I \ used
  \ u=\sqrt{\tan y} \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cfrac{2u \ du}{(\mathrm{u}^{3/2}+1)(1+u)} 
\ with \quad\sec^2y=\tan^2y-1         
 \\  \end{align}
But  I  get stuck, I have tried parcial fractions, but it doesn´t work, any step wrong?

Comment: Some steps wrong.  You write $u=\sqrt{\tan x}$ when you mean $u=\sqrt{\tan y}$ ... and then the limits for $u$ are not $0$ to $\pi/2$.  How did you get rid of $\sec^2 u$ ?? Try to re-write everything **carefully**.

Comment: Using $ \sec^2u \ as \tan^2u +1 $ , then by anterior substitution, we must get  $\tan^2u+1 $ in terms of u, and we get $ \mathrm{u}^{3/2} $

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Comment: Pretty clear, thanks.

Comment: Of course $\tan^2 u + 1 \ne u^{3/2}$.  Maybe $\tan^2 y + 1 = u^{3/2}$.  This is what I mean by writing everything **carefully**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to
make that substitution.

Watch closely.
At no time do the
fingers leave the hands.

$\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cfrac{\sqrt{\sin x}\ dx }{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}} \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cfrac{\sqrt{\sin (\pi/2-y)}\ dy }{\sqrt{\sin (\pi/2-y)}+\sqrt{\cos (\pi/2-y)}} \\
 & = -\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\cfrac{\sqrt{\cos y}\ dy }{\sqrt{\cos y}+\sqrt{\sin  y}} \quad note \ that \sin  (\pi/2-y)= \cos y, and \cos(\pi/2-y)=\sin y    \\ 
 \\
 & = \int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cfrac{\sqrt{\cos y}\ dy }{\sqrt{\cos y}+\sqrt{\sin  y}} \\
  \end{align}
$

Adding these two forms,
$2I
=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cfrac{\sqrt{\cos y}+\sqrt{\sin y}\ dy }{\sqrt{\cos y}+\sqrt{\sin  y}} 
=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}dy
=\dfrac{\pi}{2}
$
so
$I
=\dfrac{\pi}{4}
$.

Note this means that
$\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{f(\cos(x))}{f(\cos(x))+f(\sin(x))}dx
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{f(\sin(x))}{f(\cos(x))+f(\sin(x))}dx
=\dfrac{\pi}{4}
$.

The $\sqrt{}$
is a McGuffin.