# Hint for integral of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

Evaluate the integral below
 $$ \int_0^1 \frac{f(x)dx}{f(x)+f(1-x)} $$

I'm not sure about what should I do for this integral. I couldn't write Riemann sums because I don't know infimum and supremum. We only know that it's continuous and positive. How can I use continuity and positiveness for evaluating. I need some hints. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just another way of making use of the fact that

$$ \int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) dx $$

Which you can proved  very easily using substitution $u = a +b -x$.

For your problem $a = 0$ and $b=1$ and so

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)} dx = \int_0^1 \frac{f(0+1-x)}{f(0+1-x) + f(1-(0+1 -x))} = \int_0^1 \frac{f(1-x)}{f(1-x) + f(x)} $$

So if you set

$$ I =  \int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)} dx $$

then

$$ 2I = I + I = \int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)} dx + \int_0^1 \frac{f(1-x)}{f(1-x) + f(x)} dx \\
= \int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)} + \frac{f(1-x)}{f(1-x) + f(x)} dx\\
= \int_0^1 1 dx = 1 $$

Hence,

$$ I =  \int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)} dx  = \frac{1}{2}$$

This kind of problem make use of **symmetry**. Something that always make the problem much easier to solve in mathematics!

For example: Suppose you want to solve:

$$ \int_4^8 \frac{\log x}{\log x + \log(12-x)} dx$$

This integral looks very daunting, especially if you are thinking about using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (finding the antiderivative, then evaluate it at the boundary points). However, because of symmetry, and the fact that $ \int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) dx $. We can say that:

$$ I = \int_4^8 \frac{\log x}{\log x + \log(12-x)} dx =  \int_4^8 \frac{\log 12 - x}{\log 12 - x + \log(x)} dx$$

From here, we can see that

$$ 2I = \int_4^8 \frac{\log x}{\log x + \log(12-x)} + \frac{\log 12 - x}{\log 12 - x + \log(x)} dx = \int_4^8 1 dx = 4 $$

and therefore,

$$ I = \int_4^8 \frac{\log x}{\log x + \log(12-x)} dx = 2$$

There are so many definite integrals out there that can be solved very easily by this very simple but powerful technique, which is nothing more than U-Sub and making use of symmetry. It's kinda strange to me that so many calculus teachers never really mention this in class. Maybe it is very obvious for them.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Positivity is really only there to make sure $f(x)+f(1-x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, and similarly continuity can be replaced by weaker assumptions.  Substituting $u=1-x$ gives
$$
\int_0^1\frac{f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)+f(1-x)}=\int_0^1\frac{f(1-u)\,\mathrm{d}u}{f(u)+f(1-u)}
$$

Comment: @5xum I’ve no problem about substituting actually I cannot realize how can I write the value of integral. I don’t know its antiderivative

Comment: @user519955 You don't know any antiderivative of $f(x)/(f(x)-f(1-x))$, but it doesn't matter.  You only need to know the value of $\int_0^1\frac{f(x)+f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @user10354138 You meant to put a plus instead of minus in the denominator of the first fraction, right?

Comment: oops, yes $f(x)/(f(x)+f(1-x))$.

Answer (score 0):

**By cheating:**

The question hints that the value of the integral does not depend on the particular $f$. So if we take $f(x)=x$,

$$\int_0^1 x\,dx=\frac12.$$