# Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}x\sin^6x.\cos^5x.dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$
> \int_0^{2\pi}x\sin^6x.\cos^5x.dx
> $$

Set $t=\sin x\implies dt=\cos x.dx$
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi}(2\pi-x)\sin^6x.\cos^4x.\cos x.dx\\
2I=2\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^6x.(1-\sin^2x)^2.\cos x.dx\\
I=\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^6x.(1-2\sin^2x+\sin^4x).\cos x.dx=\pi\int_0^{\color{red}{?}}[t^6-2t^8+t^{10}]dt
$$
The solution given in my reference is $\dfrac{32\pi}{693}$ but if I set $x:0\to2\pi\implies t:0\to 0$, integral becomes zero, so what exactly should be the uper limit of the definite integral ?

Thanx `@José Carlos Santos`,
$$
I=\pi\bigg[\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}f(x)dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{2\pi}f(x)dx\bigg]\\
=\pi\Big[\int_0^{1}\big[\frac{t^7}{7}-\frac{2t^9}{9}+\frac{t^{11}}{11}\big]dt+\int_{1}^{-1}\big[\frac{t^7}{7}-\frac{2t^9}{9}+\frac{t^{11}}{11}\big]dt+\int_{-1}^{0}\big[\frac{t^7}{7}-\frac{2t^9}{9}+\frac{t^{11}}{11}\big]dt\Big]=0
$$
Even If I split the limits, seems like it still gives me $0$, how do I deal with it properly ?

Comment: Let $I(t)=\int_0^t f(x) dx$ with $f(x)$ to be the integrand. Then $I(t)-\frac{32 \pi}{693}$ is negative on $[0,2\pi]$!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%28%5Csin%5E6x%5Ccdot%5Ccos%5E5x%29+dx

Comment: Start with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The function that is being integrated here is $x\sin^6(x)\cos^5(x)$, not $\sin^6(x)\cos^5(x)$.

Comment: @Santos, we can remove $x$ using the link supplied above

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee my actual doubt is regarding the limit after $x$ is removed.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee my reference gives the solution $\dfrac{32\pi}{693}$, can you confirm it as zero, ie. my reference wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your substitution is not working because the substitution rule works only for one-one functions, whereas $\sin x$ is not a one-one function in $(0,2\pi)$. Instead, use the fact that
$$\int_0^{2a}f(x)dx=\int_0^af(x)+f(2a-x)dx$$
$$\implies I=\int_0^{2\pi}x\sin^6x\cos^5xdx$$
$$=\int_0^\pi(x+2\pi-x)\sin^6x\cos^5xdx$$
$$=2\pi\int_0^\pi\sin^6x\cos^5xdx$$
Again apply the same property and get 
$$I=2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^6x\cos^5x-\sin^6x\cos^5xdx$$
$$=0$$

Comment: what difference it makes, still if I take $t=\sin x$ I will still get $0$,right ?

Comment: @ss1729, You cannot substitute $t = \sin x$ in the original integral because $\sin x$ is not a one-one function.

Comment: breaking the domain and integrating separately 'd work ?

Comment: @ss1729, Yeah, that would work. But the method I am suggesting in my answer is almost mental arithmetic (if you practice this rule), so that would be a lot easier, because you'll need to do integration by parts in each of the term separately.

Comment: actually I didnt get what you are suggesting ?. $0$ is not the solution right ?

Comment: @ss1729, please tell me specifically which step you didn't understand in my solution. The answer is zero, as you can check on [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B2pi%7Dx%28sinx%29%5E6%28cosx%29%5E5dx).

Comment: @ss1729, I have edited the answer to include the last step also.

Comment: okay, so it seems my reference must be wrong !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Applying the rule

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$

$$I = \int_0^{2\pi}x\sin^6x\cos^5xdx = \int_0^{2\pi}(2\pi-x)\sin^6(2\pi-x)\cos^5(2\pi-x)dx$$

Using the fact that $\sin(2\pi-x) = -\sin x$ and $\cos(2\pi-x) = \cos x$

$$I = \pi\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^6x \cos^5x dx$$

Comment: That is *not* the function that you were supposed to integrate here.

Comment: This is the question, no?

Comment: No. The question is about $\int_0^{2\pi}x\sin^6(x)\cos^5(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Yeah, so I simplified it to remove the x term

Comment: this is something I forgot to put when I typed the question here. The real problem I am confused is about the limit. ie, after your last step.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compute$$\int_0^{\pi/2}x\sin^x(x)\cos^5(x)\,\mathrm dx\tag1$$using the substitution that you mentioned, then, since, when $x$ goes from $0$ to $\frac\pi2$, $\sin(x)$ goes from $0$ to $1$, you get$$\int_0^1\arcsin(t)(t^6-2t^8+t^{10})\,\mathrm dt=\frac{4(-5\,156+3\,465\pi)}{2\,401\,245}.$$So, $(1)=\frac{4(-5\,156+3\,465\pi)}{2\,401\,245}$.

Now, using the same idea in order to compute$$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}x\sin^x(x)\cos^5(x)\,\mathrm dx,$$what you get is$$\int_1^{-1}\bigl(\pi-\arcsin(t)\bigr)(t^6-2t^8+t^{10})\,\mathrm dt=-\frac{16\pi}{693}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Please check I have modified OP to include attempt to solve by slitting the limits as you showed, but I think it is still giving $0$ ?

Comment: Yes, the answer is $0$.

Comment: actually my reference gives the solution $\dfrac{32\pi}{693}$, so it must be wrong  ?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.