# How to Evaluate This type of trigonometric integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to Evaluate this integral and this is a practice problem of Bangladesh math Olympiad team selection :
First I tried to simplify it but confused , where to start :

$$\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\cos^4x + \sin x \cos^3 x + \sin^2x\cos^2x + \sin^3x\cos x}{\sin^4x + \cos^4x + 2\sin x\cos^3x + 2\sin^2x\cos^2x + 2\sin^3x\cos x} dx$$

Comment: Questions with no source of the problem, and no own attempts, tend to be closed.

Comment: ok i got it , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use the reflection property. Replace $x\mapsto \pi/2-x$. Adding the two expressions $2I=\pi/2$. And $I=\pi/4$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* To simplify the integrand, write $c=\cos x$ and $s=\sin x$ and notice that the denominator is of the form $$c^4+s^4+2cs(c^2+s^2+cs),$$ the numerator also being of this form except that the third term has coefficient $1$ in the place of the $2.$ Thus we simplify both simultaneously by focusing on the denominator, which becomes (since $c^2+s^2=1$) $$c^4+s^4+2cs(1+cs)=(c^2)^2+2c^2s^2+(s^2)^2+2cs=(c^2+s^2)^2+2cs=1+2cs=1+\sin 2x.$$

The numerator is $$c^4+cs(c^2+s^2+cs)=c^4+cs(1+cs)=(c^2+s^2)^2-2(cs)^2+cs+(cs)^2-s^4==1+cs-(cs)^2-s^4=1+cs-s^2(c^2+s^2)=1-s^2+cs=c^2+cs=c(c+s)=\cos x(\cos x+\sin x),$$ from where you should now be able to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just largely algebra.

Simplify the top and the bottom:

$$\text{top}= \cos x \cdot (\cos x + \sin x)$$

$$\text{bottom}= (\cos{x} + \sin{x})^2$$

Thus $$ I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos{x}}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}} \,\mathrm{dx} $$

Which by symmetry is equal to

$$ I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}} \,\mathrm{dx} $$

So that $$2I =   \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}} \,\mathrm{dx} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \mathrm{dx} = \frac{\pi}{2}. $$

So that $$I = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856