# Show that for every m and n value, $\int_0^1 x^m (1-x)^n \,dx= \int_0^1 x^n (1-x)^m \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Show that for every m and n value, $$\int_0^1 x^m (1-x)^n \,dx= \int_0^1 x^n (1-x)^m \,dx$$

I have no idea how to solve a question like that. Do I have to solve both parts of the equation and show that they're equal, or is there any other aspect that I'm not aware of?

Comment: What happens if you substitute $x\mapsto 1-x$?

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\int_0^1 x^m (1-x)^n \,dx= \int_0^1 x^n (1-x)^m \,dx$$

Your answer is in the image below:

[image]

Finally, replace $ t$ by $x$ to get the required answer.

Comment: Please use LaTeX. Handwritten solutions are not searchable and also run the risk of the images getting corrupted, moved, replaced, or outright deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!