# How to integrate a rational function with large powers of sine and cosine with no elementary anti-derivative of this.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

In my calculus class in university, we learned how to use substitution to solve integrals. But then on the quiz we got this question:

> Find the numerical value of the following integral:

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{{\sin(x)}^{22222222}}{{\sin(x)}^{22222222} + {\cos(x)}^{22222222}} dx$$

> Hint: Use the substitution $u = \frac{\pi}{2} - x$.
>
> Second hint: You cannot find an elementary anti-derivative of this.
>
> Give your answer with 3 decimal digits.
>
> Recommended time: 10 minutes

I could not understand it, even when the teacher explained it after the quiz. He was saying that it is the same for every power of the form $2n$ where $n$ is a natural number.

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Comment: Thanks man, I see the key of the solution and what we're trying to do here. But I didn't understand why $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$

Comment: @AmeerTaweel try the substitution $y=a+b-x$ and use the fact that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int _a^b f(y)\,dy$.

Comment: @overrated but then I get dx = -dy, so the integral becomes $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_b^a f(y) dy$

Comment: Keep track of the negative and switch the limits of integration.

Comment: Thank you, now I see my mistake, the limits of integration are first switched and then the negative sign from dx = -dy returns them to the original order.