# I need help with the integral $\int_{i\pi}^{3i\pi}\frac{dx}{e^{x} + 1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

While I have tried integrating the following integral
$$
I = \int_{i\pi}^{3i\pi}\frac{dx}{e^{x} + 1}
$$

I am getting zero, which is mostly wrong. Here is my attempt

Integrating I:
$$
\int_{i\pi}^{3i\pi}\frac{dx}{e^{x} + 1}
$$

Multiplying by $e^{x}$ on both the numerator and denominator, I get
$$
\int_{i\pi}^{3i\pi}\frac{e^{x}dx}{(e^{x} + 1)(e^{x})}
$$

Taking $u = e^{x} +1$ &
$du = e^{x}$

I get the new limits at $u(i\pi)$ and $u(3i\pi)$. Both of which give the value of u at 0.

Hence,
$$
\int_{0}^{0}\frac{du}{(u-1)(u)} = 0 ?
$$

I know I have made a mistake. Can anyone please show where I have made a mistake and how I can correct it. Thank you.

Comment: Does this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856 help

Comment: The integration contour now loops around $z=+1$, which happens to contain a singularity. Have you learned about Cauchy yet?

Comment: @Trebor: I have read about it a bit , but I don't know how to apply it in this case.

Comment: First step should be $y=ix$ to avoid ambiguity of limits.

Comment: Note that $e^x+1=0$ when $x=i(2n+1)\pi$.  Moreover, $e^z+1 =(z-i(2n+1)\pi)+O(((z-i(2n+1)\pi)^2)$.  Hence, this integral diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice that $e^{ix}$ is periodic on $[0,2\pi]$, so you can shift both bounds by the same amount and you will still get zero, it is the same as:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(x)dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(x)=0$$
are you sure it doesnt mean the path integral