# How to solve $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\ln(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x \ln(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$

As the properties of definite integrals don't help I attempted to integrate by parts so

$\frac{\ln(x)}{2} \int \frac{2x}{({1+x^2})^2}dx $ is the first part
which is
$\frac{-\ln(x)}{2(x^2+1)}$
the second part is therefore
$\ln(x) - \frac{\ln(1 + x^2)}{2}$
thus I= $\frac{-\ln(x)}{2(x^2+1)}- (\frac{-\ln(x)}{2(x^2+1)}$

however, this doesn't seem to make any sense as $\ln(\infty)$ isn't finite.

where am I going wrong?

Comment: Another approach:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\ln(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx\overset{x^2=t}{=}\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln t}{(1+t)^2}dt$$
Next, analyse the substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$ to evaluate the integral.

Comment: thanks, but as $x^2=t$, shouldn't $ln(x)= ln(\sqrt t))$

Comment: @fhhh which in turn becomes $\frac12\ln t$, etc. etc.

Comment: but the integral still has a ln(x+1) term, so how doesn't it become finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$1+x^2$ calls for $x=\tan y$

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\tan y\ln(\tan y)}{1+\tan^2y}=\dfrac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin2y\ln(\tan y)\ dy$$

Using [Evaluate the integral $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin^3x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}\,\mathrm dx$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856),  $$I=\dfrac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin2y\ln(\cot y)\ dy$$

Now $\ln(\cot y)=\cdots=-\ln(\tan y)$

Comment: thanks a lot!!!