# Calculating the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \frac{\sin x \cos x}{1 + \sqrt{\tan x}} \text{d}x$

Tags: calculus

I have trouble calculating the following definite integral
$$\int_{0}^{\pi / 2} \frac{\sin x \cos x}{1 + \sqrt{\tan x}} \text{d}x.$$
I tried to get the primitive function by $t = \tan \dfrac{x}{2}$ but it seemed that it is too complicated.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sinxcosx%2F%281%2Bsqrt%28tanx%29%29 there is an elementary primitive though! the defininite evaluates to 1/4 using this primtive, but i'm sure there are smarter methods given how tedious this would be

Comment: As a hint (and this a pretty useful trick): show for any $a,b$ and function $f$, $\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) \mathrm{d}x.$ Call the integral $I$, and apply this to get a second expression for $I$. Can you use these two expressions together to get something tractable?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Comment: Try $\sqrt{\tan(x)}=t$ for the antiderivative

Comment: `Integrate[Sin[x]*Cos[x]/(1 + Sqrt[Tan[x]]), {x, 0, Pi/2}]`  $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: $$I_0=\int_0^{\pi / 2} \frac{\sin x \cos x}{1 + \sqrt{\tan x}}dx=\int_0^{\pi / 2} \frac{\tan x \cos^2 x}{1 + \sqrt{\tan x}}dx\overset{t=\tan x}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{t}{(1+t^2)^2}\frac{dt}{1+\sqrt t}$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt t}\,\bigg|_0^\infty-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^4}\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}$$
$$I_1=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^4}\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}\overset{x=\frac{1}{t}}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^4}{1+t^4}\frac{dt}{(1+t)^2}\Rightarrow 2I_1=\int_0^\infty\frac{1+t^4}{1+t^4}\frac{dt}{(1+t)^2}=1$$ $$I_0=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on @stochasticboy321's comment, you get
$$
2I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1+\sqrt{\tan(x)}}\mathrm{d}x + \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(u)\sin(u)}{1+\sqrt{\cot(u)}}\mathrm{d}u}_{\color{darkblue}{u = \frac{\pi}{2}-x}}  = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(x)\cos(x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(2x) \mathrm{d}x
$$
Since
$$
\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{t}} + \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{t}}}  = \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{t}} + \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t}+1} = \frac{1+\sqrt{t}}{1+\sqrt{t}}=1
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $\tan x=u^2$ then
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x\cos x}{1+\sqrt{\tan x}}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2u^3}{(u+1)(u^4+1)^2}du$$
We can still do a similar trick. It is not too late. Let $u\rightarrow 1/u$ in the last integral, then, $$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2u^4}{(u+1)(u^4+1)^2}du$$
and hence
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2u^3+2u^4}{(u+1)(u^4+1)^2}du=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^3}{(u^4+1)^2}du=\left.-\frac{1}{4(u^4+1)}\right\rvert_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{4}.$$